# What is the best apporach to handle large set of RealmObject records in RealmListView

Tags: react-native, realm, realm-list

To display large set of records (around 10,000) in Realm-js ListView and keeping the RealmObjects wrapped in Results (using slice will detach the RealmObject, so not prefered slice()) followed below approach,

```
import { ListView } from 'realm/react-native';

var category = realm.objects('Category');
const categoryDS = new ListView.DataSource({rowHasChanged: (r1, r2) => r1.name !== r2.name});
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
return {
dataSource: recordDS.cloneWithRows(category),
};
}
```

Since fetching all the records and rendering all the records in ListView at single shot will not be the best practice.

Do we have any better approach to handle large set of records, something like display 10 records initially and on scrolling further add another set of 10 records and so on?

Answer (score 0):

The Realm ListView API is exactly the same as React.ListView, so you can refer to the ListView documentation: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/listview.html

Comment: I am aware that Realm ListView is same as React ListView. Is there any way in Realm js to fetch first 10 records render it in ListView and fetch another set of 10 records when the user reaches scroll end...